# Force a C# Application to run in 32bit mode on a 64bit server

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, 32-bit

A client of ours is running an old version of our software which was built with "Any CPU" targeted. The software uses the Microsoft Tablet SDK which is a 32bit only application.

They are attempting to install this on a 64 bit pc and obviously having issues because of the 32bit SDK not being visible to our software running in 64bit mode.

Rebuilding their version of the software is not an option (source control screwup) but they are planning an upgrade in the future.

So i need a temporary workaround to force this application to run in 32 bit mode.

I've tried launching it from a 32bit command prompt but this still runs it in 64bit mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess maybe [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) could be of help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the [CorFlags.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), to force the assembly to be loaded in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Haha and me too! (Btw, command line is `corflags nameOfTheApp.exe /32BITREQ+` and I'm not sure it'll work if the assembly is strong-name signed.

Comment: looks like it should do the trick. Ill test it and let you know.